# Error while parsing JSON in Swift, [String:Any] won't work

Tags: json, swift, xcode, macos

I'm trying to parse [this JSON](https://gist.github.com/DesWurstes/00baf946bd6d27e7e9355bd6e9969230) in Swift 3, but it crashes.

Here's the code

```swift
do{
   let data1: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: NSURL(string: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/DesWurstes/00baf946bd6d27e7e9355bd6e9969230/raw/a0de898faea8ddedb11b0db516967d0666255633/gist.json") as! URL)
   let jsono = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data1, options: []) as! [String: Any]
}catch{
   // catch isn't used here.
}
```

Here's the error I get when it crashes:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x7fffe9cb9c08) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fffe9cba158).
```

It crashes because **not all of the elements of the array are string**. (The root of the JSON is an array.)

To prevent it from crashing, changing the third line with this will be suitable:

```
let jsono = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data1, options: [])
```

But then, its type will be `Any` and I won't be able to parse it with

```
let string = jsono["something"] as! [String: Any] // Type "Any" has no subscript members
```

and this code won't run:

```
if let array = jsono as? [String: Any] {
   print("test") // Doesn't print
}
```

While trying to fix error in the first code, I thought this code may work (Because it says can't convert Array to Dictionary):

```
let jsono = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data1, options: []) as! [String]
```

but it results...

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7fffe9cba108) to 'NSString' (0x7fffea072f38).
```

Then how can I parse this JSON?

Comment: Your JSON is an Array. So it can't be `[String:Any]` which is a Dictionary. So it's `[Any]` (array) at least. Now, if we look more, it's an Array of dictionaries which keys are Strings, so it's `as [[String:Any]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the JSON response returned from server is an array containing dictionaries of type `[String: Any]` so you can do:

```
if let array = jsono as? [[String: Any]] {
  print("test") // Will print

  for dictionary in array {
    print(dictionary["url"] as! String)
  }
}
```

Here you can [download the playground](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a52j4p8a2y835wp/AADwtDmd0rbqCj0oeXhlX8Vwa?dl=0) I've written to test it out.

Comment: Nice! Also have you tried [IBM Swift sandbox](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl)? It's a playground that doesn't need to be downloaded, and it'd be easier to test.

Comment: No I haven't tried yet. But thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

you have parse array response so you need to type cast **json as? [[String: Any]]**..
if your response is dictonary then you need to parse like **json as? [String: Any]**

Answer (score 0):

```
func Callservice()
{
    let jsonUrlString = "url"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {

            let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data)
            self.arrayData = courses

            print(courses)


        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }



        }.resume()
}



struct course:decodable{
let name:string?
}
```